# replace if/else with while/if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

is it possible to replace a `if/else` statement with `while` and `if` statement(s) (say, we're working in C)?  If it's possible, can you please share an example.  So, say I have

```
if (cond1)
    exec1
else 
    exec2
```

And I really want to get rid of the `if/else` and just use `if/while` constructs.

Is it enough for a Turing Complete language to have `while/if` statements (for the control flow)?

How would I do it with `if/else` constructs?

(this is not a homework, this is out of curiosity)

Comment: Unless this is meant to be used for some code golf I don't see why you'd want to do that. Also I don't see a way to implement the `else` branch using some kind of while loop construct. The if-then branch yes, but not the else.

Comment: if-else can be replaced by switch-case and conditional operators.

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat clunky, but assuming that the execution of either branch doesn't change the condition, you could replace an if-else construct with a couple of whiles:
Assume the original is:

```
if (cond) {
   exec1();
else {
   exec2();
}
```

It could be replaced with only `if`s:

```
if (cond) {
    exec1();
}
if (!cond) {
    exec2();
}
```

Or with `while`s:

```
while (cond) {
    exec1();
    break;
}
while (!cond) {
    exec2();
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a general replacement of the `if() ... else ...` construct, you can cache the result of the condition:

```
int condition = cond1;
if(condition) exec1;
if(!condition) exec2;
```

That way you avoid issues with sideeffects in `cond1` and `exec1`.

Concerning your question about turing completeness:
As Paul Griffiths notes, `if()` and `goto` are sufficient. However, so are `if()` and recursion. You can replace any `while(cond1) exec1;` loop with a self recursive function:

```
void loopy(/*whatever state the loop touches*/) {
    if(cond1) {
        exec1;
        loopy(/*pass on the current state*/);
    }
}
```

This fact is heavily abused in functional languages like lisp and scheme. When you learn programming in these languages, you are taught to write your recursions in such a way (tail recursion) that the compiler can figure out that you intended to write a loop and optimize accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need `while`, you just need to be able to compare and to be able to branch, in other words, `if` and `goto`. In the following program, the functions `test_normally()` and `test_subnormally()` are equivalent:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void exec1(void)
{
    puts("exec1() called");
}

void exec2(void)
{
    puts("exec2() called");
}

void exec3(void)
{
    puts("exec3() called");
}

void test_normally(void)
{
    int cond1 = 0;
    int cond2 = 1;
    int i = 5;

    /*  First if test  */

    if ( cond1 )
        exec1();
    else
        exec2();

    puts("First if test over.");

    /*  Second if test  */

    if ( cond2 )
        exec1();
    else
        exec2();

    puts("Second if test over.");

    /*  While test  */

    while ( i > 0 ) {
        exec3();
        --i;
    }

    puts("Loop test over.");
}

void test_subnormally(void)
{
    int cond1 = 0;
    int cond2 = 1;
    int i = 5;

    /*  First if test  */

    if ( !cond1 )
        goto cond1_false;

    exec1();
    goto cond1_end;

cond1_false:
    exec2();

cond1_end:
    puts("First if test over.");

    /*  Second if test  */

    if ( !cond2 )
        goto cond2_false;

    exec1();
    goto cond2_end;

cond2_false:
    exec2();

cond2_end:
    puts("Second if test over.");

    /*  While test  */

loop_start:
    if ( !(i > 0) )
        goto loop_end;

    exec3();
    --i;
    goto loop_start;

loop_end:
    puts("Loop test over.");
}

int main(void)
{
    test_normally();
    putchar('\n');
    test_subnormally();
    return 0;
}
```

and output:

```
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$ ./goto
exec2() called
First if test over.
exec1() called
Second if test over.
exec3() called
exec3() called
exec3() called
exec3() called
exec3() called
Loop test over.

exec2() called
First if test over.
exec1() called
Second if test over.
exec3() called
exec3() called
exec3() called
exec3() called
exec3() called
Loop test over.
paul@local:~/src/sandbox$
```

By comparing the two functions, hopefully you can see why `if` and `while` and all their friends are better than the alternatives.

`test_subnormally()` is actually very close to what the processor is actually doing, after your C source gets compiled into machine code. Here's the assembly output of `test_normally()` from gcc on a 64 bit Intel processor - you can see that there's almost a one-to-one mapping between the assembly instructions and the C source for the other function, `test_subnormally()`:

```
.LC3:
    .string "First if test over."
.LC4:
    .string "Second if test over."
.LC5:
    .string "Loop test over."
    .text
    .globl  test_normally
    .type   test_normally, @function
test_normally:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc          # // Function entry
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $0, -8(%rbp)    # // -8(%rbp) is cond1
    movl    $1, -12(%rbp)   # // -12(%rbp) is cond2
    movl    $5, -4(%rbp)    # // -4(%rbp) is i
    cmpl    $0, -8(%rbp)    # if ( !cond1 )    
    je  .L5                 # goto cond1_false;
    call    exec1           # exec1();
    jmp .L6                 # goto cond1_end;
.L5:                        # cond1_false:
    call    exec2           # exec2();
.L6:                        # cond1_end:
    movl    $.LC3, %edi     # // move "First if test over" to %edi
    call    puts            # puts("First if test over");
    cmpl    $0, -12(%rbp)   # if ( !cond2 )
    je  .L7                 # goto cond2_false;
    call    exec1           # exec1();
    jmp .L8                 # goto cond2_end;
.L7:                        # cond2_false:
    call    exec2           # exec2();
.L8:                        # cond2_end:
    movl    $.LC4, %edi     # // move "Second if test over" to %edi
    call    puts            # puts("Second if test over");
    jmp .L9                 # goto loop_start;
.L10:                       # loop_body:
    call    exec3           # exec3();
    subl    $1, -4(%rbp)    # --i;
.L9:                        # loop_start:
    cmpl    $0, -4(%rbp)    # if ( !(i > 0) ) ...
    jg  .L10                # ...goto loop_body;
    movl    $.LC5, %edi     # // move "Loop test over" to %edi
    call    puts            # puts("Loop test over");
    leave                   # // Function exit
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

The compiler has here chosen to put the loop pieces in a slightly different order, but other than that it reads almost exactly like the C source for `test_subnormally()`. The underlying reason we have `if`, and `while`, and their friends in C is precisely so that we don't have to write code that looks like this, but that level of simplicity and spaghetti-like code is what processors ultimately end up executing (and is all you need to be Turing-complete), so we have a compiler to turn something that looks more understandable and maintainable to human beings into the kind of messiness that processors are perfectly happy with.

Answer (score 0):

These are equivalent, if `cond1` is not changed in `exec1`.

```
if (cond1) exec1 else exec2

if (cond1) exec1
if (!cond1) exec2
```

No while needed.

Answer (score 0):

The if, else can be replaced with:
using **If** :

if (condition cond1 is true)
 {

execute exec1;

}

if (!(condition cond1 is true)) //condition is false

{
  execute exec2;

}

using **While** loop :

while (condition cond1 is true)
 {

execute exec1;

}

while (!(condition cond1 is true)) //condition is false

{
  execute exec2;

}

Comment: You forgot the break, otherwise your while would not stop

Comment: No, the condition is being checked at each iteration, the condition is also being modified inside the while loops. For e.g. iterator++;